# Underline list item to page width

Tags: lists, underline

I am currently working on my thesis template, which requires the title to be formatted as shown below:

[image: Sample title]

The title begins with a fixed "THESIS:" label, and the title itself is placed with underlines extended to end of line. In the previous versions I drew the lines manually and used `\tl_range:Nnn` to separate the title into two lines, since they have constant widths. However, I quickly ran into the problems of how to break lines correctly. There are short titles which need only one line, and longer ones which needs more than two.

I am now considering the `list` environment, but out of idea how to implement this. The packages for underlining either fail to break lines correctly inside a list, or do not support Chinese, which is the actual language for this template. On the other hand, would it be better to not rely on these packages but draw fixed lines instead? Then how can I determine how many lines I need?

To sum up:

- "THESIS:~" label
- Justified text
- Underlines of fixed width
- Chinese support

I can also provide a test project that can only be compiled with LuaTeX. It is a pity that the  `lua-ul`  package ignores spaces. It is also worth mentioning that the minimal-but-not-working example uses LaTeX3 style, which is what I am using in the template file.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3,lipsum,lua-ul}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__test_print_title:
  {
    \list { THESIS:~ }
      {
        \labelwidth  \c_zero_dim
        \labelsep    \c_zero_dim
        \leftmargin  \c_zero_dim
        \rightmargin \c_zero_dim
      }
    \item \underLine{\lipsum[][1-2]\hfill}
    \endlist
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \maketesttitle { }
  { \__test_print_title: }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketesttitle
\end{document}
```

I am very much grateful for any help provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a \vbox, then decompose its lines and run paragraph brreaking algorithm again with underlined lines.

```
\newbox\labeltext
\setbox\labeltext=\hbox{THESIS: }

\def\spectitle#1{%
   \setbox0=\vbox{\hangindent=\wd\labeltext \hangafter=-1 
      \leftskip=0pt plus1fill \rightskip=\leftskip \parindent=0pt #1\par
      \global\setbox2=\hbox{}
      \loop
         \setbox1=\lastbox \unskip\unpenalty
         \unless\ifvoid1 \global\setbox2=\hbox{\createubox\penalty0\unhbox2}
         \repeat
    }
    {\baselineskip=20pt
    \noindent\copy\labeltext\unhbox2 \par}   
}
\def\createubox{% create underlined box
    \vtop{\box1\kern-\prevdepth\kern2pt\hrule}}

% test
\hsize=10cm

\spectitle{Text dgdh ajhjd ja jsd ba gha dh dag sgfyie csf ufe w eeb ui vee
           ja jsd ba gha dh dag sgfyie csf ufe w ee}

\bye
```

You need not any package, only TeX primitives are used here.

Comment: Thanks for your timely help! I believe the "paragraph breaking algorithm" you presented is the key to solving my problem, and these commands do meet my requirements. There are two minor adaptations that I will make later by myself (or other kind members or this community). First the second line should start left-aligned. Second for code style consistency I may convert this into LaTeX3 syntax. Shouldn't be big problems though :)

Comment: If the next lines should be left-aligned then set `0pt plus1fill` only to `\rightskip` register. Ad second: my style is very consistent: I am using only TeX primitives and basic macros. LaTeX3 syntax is not so consistent from my point of view because you sometimes need to use primitive syntax too.

Comment: I find more evidence for your points through your posts. It doesn't bother to change my paradigm and try some primitive TeX : )